# How to get the return value of a callback function [API Request]

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, request, ecmascript-5

I want to do an API request and display the body in a table on my site. I'm using Node.JS, React and Request. This is my code:

```js
var requestResult = Request.get('https://test.ipdb.io/api/v1/assets/?search=asdf', (err, res, body) => {
  return body;
});
```

This is obviously not working. I can console.log(body), but I want the API response to be available outside the callback function. Is that possible?

Comment: Callbacks are not meant to return a value. Returning a value is more of a synchronous way of writing the code. In a callback, a value needs to be set and then the next function is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using callbacks approach, then you should continue your job in callback function.
Example:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Request.get('https://test.ipdb.io/api/v1/assets/?search=asdf', (err, res, body) => {
    console.log(body);
    // do any other job here
    res.send(body);
  });
});
```

Other approaches you can use in 2017:

- [promises](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators/)
- coroutines + generators
- async + await

You can gain more info [here](https://www.codementor.io/codeforgeek/manage-async-nodejs-callback-example-code-du107q1pn).

Comment: Wow... I used to do PHP for some years but this seems just way too complex for me. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Spend some time understanding this. It's the basics of how things work in nodejs.